Nextjs Deployment to linux server
We've deployed nextjs app to linux server, and we configured httpd.conf file to point the site to
build directory , as build folder doesnt have index.html we are not sure abt how we can point site to build folder
however we tried to navigate to the site with below reverseproxy settings.
ProxyPreserveHost On
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
DocumentRoot "/opt/ui/client/build"
ServerName **.*.**.***
<Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
        ProxyPassReverse https://**.*.**.***
</Location>

Above solution wont suffice our requirement as we have multiple sites and redirect on "/" is redirecting all request to this site
Can anyone help us to implement this requirement?
we need to deploy the client seperately on linux apache site,we do have seperate express server for backend and our client site is hybrid app as it has both client/server rendered components.
Nextjs version:
"next": "14.2.1",
"next-i18n-router": "^5.4.0",
"next-nprogress-bar": "^2.3.11",
"react": "^18",

Because Nextj14 support BE and FE, so you can't run as production by index.html file,
you need to start nextjs at port 3000 yarn start
and to use for production you can use pm2
